# Can't get the play and pause buttons to work properly with iFrame

Tags: javascript, react-native

I've been trying to embed random YouTube videos from an array in my React Native app. This works well so far, every time I go to another screen and then back, another video shows up! Now I've been trying to implement external pause/play buttons! These work well when there's only one YouTube link in the array! However, if I add the other links, the play/pause buttons start glitching and every time I press one it either does nothing, leads to another video or pauses the video! I don't think it's random though, there seem so be a system of what's not working but I simply cannot figure it out! One guess is, that the issue is with the states of 'playing' and that sometimes the video doesn't play even though playing === true? Well, idk, maybe one of you can help! here's the code:

```
import React, { useState, useCallback, useRef } from "react";
import { Button, View, Alert, Text } from "react-native";
import YoutubePlayer from "react-native-youtube-iframe";
import {NeuView, NeuButton} from 'react-native-neu-element';
import { set } from "react-native-reanimated";
//import {LinearGradient} from 'expo-linear-gradient';
//import {LinearGradient} from 'react-native-linear-gradient';

//example vids
const videos = [
  'iNQAp2RtXBw',
  'AJqiFpAl8Ew',
  'IdoD2147Fik',
]

const randomVideo = () =>
videos[Math.floor(Math.random() * videos.length)];

export default function funnyVideos() {
  const [playing, setPlaying] = useState(false);

  function pause() {
    if (playing === true) {
      setPlaying(false)
    }
  }
  function play() {
    if (playing === false) {
      setPlaying(true)
    }
  }
  
    
 

return (
    <View  alignItems = 'center' >
      <NeuView style = {{marginTop: '15%'}}  width = {330} height = {200} color = '#f2f2f2' borderRadius = {20} >
        <View overflow = 'hidden' height = {169}  style = {{position: 'relative', marginTop: 0}} justifyContent = 'center' alignContent = 'center' borderRadius = {10}> 

          <YoutubePlayer
            height={'100%'}
            width={300}
            videoId = {randomVideo()}
            play = {playing}
          />
      </View>
    </NeuView>
    
    <View flexDirection = 'row'>
      <NeuButton style = {{marginTop: 60, marginRight: 45}}  width = {100}  height = {100} color = '#f2f2f2' title={playing ? "pause" : "play"} onPress = {play} borderRadius = {20}>
        <Text>
          play
        </Text>
      </NeuButton>
      <NeuButton style = {{marginTop: 60}}  width = {100}  height = {100} color = '#f2f2f2' title={playing ? "pause" : "play"} onPress = {pause} borderRadius = {20}>
        <Text>
          pause
        </Text>
      </NeuButton>
    </View>
      <NeuButton style = {{marginTop: 45}} width = {250}  height = {100} color = '#f2f2f2' title={playing ? "pause" : "play"} borderRadius = {20}>
        <Text>
          Next Video
        </Text>
      </NeuButton>

    
    </View>
  ); 
}
```

Comment: Set your random video in a useState so you don't call `randomVideo()` every render.

Comment: How exactly can I do that?:D Im not so good with Hooks yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the job and also I have taken the liberty to refine some code.

```html
import React, { useState, useCallback, useRef } from "react";
import { Button, View, Alert, Text } from "react-native";
import YoutubePlayer from "react-native-youtube-iframe";
import {NeuView, NeuButton} from 'react-native-neu-element';
import { set } from "react-native-reanimated";

//example vids
const videos = [
  'iNQAp2RtXBw',
  'AJqiFpAl8Ew',
  'IdoD2147Fik',
]

const randomVideo = () =>
videos[Math.floor(Math.random() * videos.length)];

export default function FunnyVideos() {
  const [playing, setPlaying] = useState(false);
    const [videoId, setRandomVideoId] = useState(randomVideo());

  const pauseOrPlay = () => useCallback({
    setPlaying(!playing)
  },[playing])

  return (
    <View  alignItems = 'center' >
      <NeuView style = {{marginTop: '15%'}}  width = {330} height = {200} color = '#f2f2f2' borderRadius = {20} >
        <View overflow = 'hidden' height = {169}  style = {{position: 'relative', marginTop: 0}} justifyContent = 'center' alignContent = 'center' borderRadius = {10}> 

          <YoutubePlayer
            height={'100%'}
            width={300}
            videoId = {videoId}
            play = {playing}
          />
      </View>
    </NeuView>
    
    <View flexDirection = 'row'>
      <NeuButton style = {{marginTop: 60, marginRight: 45}}  width = {100}  height = {100} color = '#f2f2f2' title={playing ? "pause" : "play"} onPress = {play} borderRadius = {20}>
        <Text>
          play
        </Text>
      </NeuButton>
      <NeuButton style = {{marginTop: 60}}  width = {100}  height = {100} color = '#f2f2f2' title={playing ? "pause" : "play"} onPress = {pause} borderRadius = {20}>
        <Text>
          pause
        </Text>
      </NeuButton>
    </View>
      <NeuButton style = {{marginTop: 45}} width = {250}  height = {100} color = '#f2f2f2' title={playing ? "pause" : "play"} borderRadius = {20}>
        <Text>
          Next Video
        </Text>
      </NeuButton>

    
    </View>
  ); 
}
```

Comment: *"This will do the job"* doesn't really explain what was changed  or why

Comment: Added a state for randomVideoId so that everytime when you come back to this page, randomVideo function is not called. 



Modified the play and pause method and incorporated them in a single method

Comment: Best to explain those things in the answer which you can edit any time

Comment: Thanks a lot to both of you for your time and help! I still can't get it to work though:(  now it says that the '!' from setPlaying(!playing) at line 22 is an unexpected token! I tried out multiple things now but I just can't get it to work!